# Erro ao fazer upload com IdHTTP firemonkey android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

estou usando este código para fazer os **testes** de upload de arquivos para meu servidor.

arquivo `html` onde seleciono o arquivo.

```
<html>
<body> 
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Arquivo</label>
  <input type="file" name="userfile" />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

e o `php` que faz o upload:

```
<?php
 $uploaddir = 'erro/';
 $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

 echo '<pre>';
 if   (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Arquivo valido e enviado com sucesso.\n";
 }
 else {
    echo "Possivel ataque de upload de arquivo!\n";
 } 

 echo 'Aqui esta mais informacoes de debug:';
 print_r($_FILES);

 print "</pre>";
?>
```

esta funcionando perfeitamente, mas quando tento enviar algum arquivo pelo aplicativo com o código abaixo recebo um erro.

```
procedure export_erro;
var
    params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
    folder,resposta: string;
begin

    try

      folder:= 'storage/emulated/0/erros/';

        if not Directoryexists(folder) then
            forcedirectories(folder);

        if FileExists(folder+'aa.txt') then
        begin

            params := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;

            params.AddFile('userfile', folder+'aa.txt', 'text/plain');

            IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
            IdHTTP1.Request.Clear;
            IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'UTF-8';
            IdHTTP1.Request.ContentEncoding := 'multipart/form-data';

            resposta:= IdHTTP1.Post('http://site.com/upload.php', params);

        end
        else
            ShowMessage('arquivo não existe!');

    except on e:exception do
        ShowMessage(e.Message);
    end;

    FreeAndNil(params);

end.
```

o erro é este

> HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable

Answer (score 0):

**Erro 406: Não aceitável**. O recurso solicitado é apenas capaz de gerar conteúdo não aceitáveis ​​de acordo com os cabeçalhos Accept enviados na solicitação([Link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP#406_N%C3%A3o_Aceit%C3%A1vel)).

Problema de *content type*. Pode ser algum Mime Type que o servidor não consegue manipular, erros de enconding inválido, etc.